# Error with MongoDB aggregation $reduce operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I recently upgraded my Java app from using MongoDB client 3 to 4 (the cluster has been on v4 for awehile, finally getting around to the client).

One of my aggregations, which uses the `$reduce` operator, has started causing errors after the upgrade.

Here's the error message from the server:

```
'$reduce found an unknown argument: $and'
```

And here's the snippet of code:

```
    List<Bson> agg = Arrays.asList(
        unwind("$playlist.songs", new UnwindOptions().preserveNullAndEmptyArrays(true)),
        project(
                fields(
                        excludeId(), 
                        computed("title", "$playlist.songs.title"), 
                        computed("artist", 
                                eq("$reduce", 
                                        and(
                                                eq("input", "$details.playlist.songs.artists.artist_name"), 
                                                eq("initialValue", ""), 
                                                eq("in", eq("$concat", Arrays.asList("$$value", " ", "$$this")))))))),
```

I originally generated this snippet using the Mongo Compass tool, and I have tried re-generating it using the latest release (v4) but it gives me the same snippet.

I also tried replacing the `$reduce` arguments with plain `Document` objects, but I started running into issues with dollar signs and field names. I would prefer to keep using native aggregation helpers if possible.

---

Update: I have found a work around, which is dropping the `and` operator and using purely native BSON API for the *value* of the `$reduce` operator with pure BSON objects:

```
eq("$reduce",
    new BsonDocument("input", new BsonString("$details.playlist.songs.artists.artist_name"))
        .append("initialValue", new BsonString(""))
        .append("in", new BsonDocument("$concat", new BsonArray(Arrays.asList(
            new BsonString("$$value"),
            new BsonString(" "),
            new BsonString("$$this"))))))))),
```

Comment: Your code compiled fine with MongoDB Java Driver 3.12.2. I am running MongoDB 4.2.8 on Java SE 11. Syntactically, the last comma (`,`) in your code is not required and needs a closing bracket `)` for the `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: This isn't the full aggregation pipeline code, just the relevant piece showing the `$reduce` stage, so I didn't cut and paste the entire thing. But in my app it compiles fine and is syntactically correct.

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Comment: I stated the problem in the original question...the aggregation returns an error: `'$reduce found an unknown argument: $and'`. On client 3.x it worked fine, but for some reason using client 4.x doesn't work (even though the server has been on 4.x for several months now).

Comment: So, its a runtime error... In such case, post the stack trace. Is it a compile-time error with Java driver v3.x?

Comment: The code compiled fine with Java Driver 4.0.5. Its a runtime error.

Comment: A little more background: this is a Spring Boot application thats been using 3.x driver for over a year without issue. A few months ago, the server was upgraded to 4.x and everything continued to work fine. This week, I upgraded the app to Spring Boot 2.3, which forced the Mongo driver to 4.x, and now I get the runtime error. The stack trace is all mongo DB internal, not sure it would be helpful.